# Erro de migração, Flask

Tags: python, app, flask

está aparecendo, "NameError: name 'app' is not defined" meu codico

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///storage.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app) 
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

from app.controllers import default

from app import manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
 manager.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ficou um pouco complicado de entender o seu código, mas pelo erro da pra perceber que a sua aplicação "app" não ta sendo definida, logo, o problema se encontra na criação da instância do objeto Flask. Pelo que eu entendi, você escreveu:

```
app = Flask(name)
```

Na verdade, o correto seria:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Por isso que ele não está conseguindo criar o app.

Comment: Lembrando que __name__ é uma variável especial do python que referencia o script que está rodando, se esse for o script principal, então ele ira retornar a string __main__.

Comment: pior, que está app = flask(__name__)

Comment: eu fiz umas alterações, alguns teste e agora aparece isso : usage: run.py [-?] {db,shell,runserver} ...

positional arguments:
  {db,shell,runserver}
    db                  Perform database migrations
    shell               Runs a Python shell inside Flask application context.
    runserver           Runs the Flask development server i.e. app.run()

optional arguments:
  -?, --help            show this help message and exit

Comment: Certo, vamos lá, como você está botando pra rodar? "python nome.py" só? Se você fizer isso ele vai te passar os default commands, pois o manager é usado de forma que você passe argumentos pela linha de comando, que podem ser o "runserver" que funciona como um "flask run", o "shell" que inicia um shell python pra voce importar o que vc precisa e executar, ou passar direto através de um decorador. Dá uma olhada nesse link da doc na parte dos Defaults Commands : https://flask-script.readthedocs.io/en/latest/